# How to get the perfect border and make the window to always stay on top?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have this `VB +WinForms` Application . The UI is captured in the image below

[image]

The `Add/Edit Material Window` has its own unique `Aqua blue` color border .

The `VB` code behind is

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Friend Class FrmAddMaterial
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Friend ErrorFlag As ErrorFlagType
    Friend SavePath As String
    Public Event UpdateMaterialFile()

    Private Sub CmdAdd_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdAdd.Click
        Dim AddEditMat As New AddEditMaterialDialog
        With AddEditMat
            .TxtMaterialName.Text = ""
            .TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = ""
            .TxtDryRefractiveIndex.Text = ""
            .TxtLinearExpansion.Text = ""
            .TxtRadialExpansion.Text = ""
            .txtMDPrefix.Text = ""
            .TxtMaterialNumber.Text = Me.LstMaterials.Items.Count.ToString
            .Text = "Add Material"
            .SavePath = SavePath
            .Show()
        End With
        If LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, ErrorFlag)
        Else
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, 0, ErrorFlag)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdEdit_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdEdit.Click
        Dim MaterialData As MaterialType
        MaterialData = GetMaterialData(Me.LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, _
                                       SavePath, _
                                       ErrorFlag)
        Dim MatRef As New AddEditMaterialDialog
        With MatRef
            .TxtMaterialName.Text = MaterialData.MaterialName
            .TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.WetRefractiveIndex.ToString
            .TxtDryRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.DryRefractiveIndex.ToString
            .TxtLinearExpansion.Text = MaterialData.LinearExpansion.ToString
            .TxtRadialExpansion.Text = MaterialData.RadiusExpansion.ToString
            .txtMDPrefix.Text = MaterialData.MDPrefix
            .TxtMaterialNumber.Text = MaterialData.Index.ToString
            .Text = "Edit Material"
            .SavePath = SavePath
            .Show()
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdRemoveMaterial_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdRemoveMaterial.Click
        Dim Msg As String
        Dim MsgVal As Short
        Msg = "Are you sure that you want to remove this material?"
        MsgVal = MsgBox(Msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, InfoMsg)
        If MsgVal = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            If LstMaterials.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                RemoveMaterialData(LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, _
                                   SavePath, _
                                   ErrorFlag)
                Me.LstMaterials.Items.RemoveAt((LstMaterials.SelectedIndex))
                If LstMaterials.Items.Count > 0 Then
                    LstMaterials.SelectedIndex = 0
                End If
                Call UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, ErrorFlag)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmAddMaterial_Enter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Enter
        If LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, ErrorFlag)
        Else
            UpdateMaterialScreen(Me, 0, ErrorFlag)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmAddMaterial_Load(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Width = 278
        Me.Height = 289
        SavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ConfigSoftData.DirectoryData.AppPath, "Mold\lib")
    End Sub

    Private Sub LstMaterials_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles LstMaterials.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim MaterialData As MaterialType
        MaterialData = GetMaterialData(LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, _
                                       SavePath, _
                                       ErrorFlag)
        With Me
            .TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.WetRefractiveIndex.ToString
            .TxtMDPrefix.Text = MaterialData.MDPrefix
        End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub FrmAddMaterial_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
        RaiseEvent UpdateMaterialFile()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I tried to convert the Application UI to `C#` and matched all the properties set in the VB forms but I am getting something like this

[image]

The `C#` code behind is

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Mold_Power_Suite.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Mold_Power_Suite.View
{
    public partial class FrmAddMaterial : Form
    {
        public FrmAddMaterial()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //FormClosed += FrmAddMaterial_FormClosed;
            //Load += FrmAddMaterial_Load;
            //Enter += FrmAddMaterial_Enter;
        }
        internal Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.ErrorFlagType ErrorFlag;
    internal string SavePath;
    public event UpdateMaterialFileEventHandler UpdateMaterialFile;
    public delegate void UpdateMaterialFileEventHandler();

    private void CmdAdd_Click(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        AddEditMaterialDialog AddEditMat = new AddEditMaterialDialog();
        //var _with1 = AddEditMat;
        AddEditMat.TxtMaterialName.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.TxtDryRefractiveIndex.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.TxtLinearExpansion.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.TxtRadialExpansion.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.txtMDPrefix.Text = "";
        AddEditMat.TxtMaterialNumber.Text = this.LstMaterials.Items.Count.ToString();
        AddEditMat.Text = "Add Material";
        AddEditMat.SavePath = SavePath;
        AddEditMat.Show();
        if (LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1) {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex,ref ErrorFlag);
        } else {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, 0, ref ErrorFlag);
        }
    }

    private void CmdEdit_Click(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.MaterialType MaterialData = default(Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.MaterialType);

        short RIN=Convert.ToInt16( this.LstMaterials.SelectedIndex);
        MaterialData = ModSoftInputMod.GetMaterialData(ref RIN, ref SavePath, ref ErrorFlag);
        AddEditMaterialDialog MatRef = new AddEditMaterialDialog();
        //var _with2 = MatRef;
        MatRef.TxtMaterialName.Text = MaterialData.MaterialName;
        MatRef.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.WetRefractiveIndex.ToString();
        MatRef.TxtDryRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.DryRefractiveIndex.ToString();
        MatRef.TxtLinearExpansion.Text = MaterialData.LinearExpansion.ToString();
        MatRef.TxtRadialExpansion.Text = MaterialData.RadiusExpansion.ToString();
        MatRef.txtMDPrefix.Text = MaterialData.MDPrefix;
        MatRef.TxtMaterialNumber.Text = MaterialData.Index.ToString();
        MatRef.Text = "Edit Material";
        MatRef.SavePath = SavePath;
        MatRef.Show();
    }

    private void CmdRemoveMaterial_Click(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
    string Msg = null;
        //short MsgVal = 0; // Commented this line and made MsgVal as var
        Msg = "Are you sure that you want to remove this material?";
        var MsgVal = Interaction.MsgBox(Msg, MsgBoxStyle.YesNo,ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables. InfoMsg);
        if (MsgVal == MsgBoxResult.Yes) 
        {
            if (LstMaterials.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                short value = Convert.ToInt16((LstMaterials.SelectedIndex));
               ModSoftOutput. RemoveMaterialData(ref value, SavePath,ref  ErrorFlag);
                this.LstMaterials.Items.RemoveAt((LstMaterials.SelectedIndex));
                if (LstMaterials.Items.Count > 0) {
                    LstMaterials.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex,ref ErrorFlag);
            }
        }
    }

        //This event is not being fired up . The code below has been pasted into FrmAddMaterial_Load()
    private void FrmAddMaterial_Enter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1) {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex,ref ErrorFlag);
        } else {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, 0,ref ErrorFlag);
        }
    }

    private void FrmAddMaterial_Load(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        this.Width = 278;
        this.Height = 289;
        SavePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ModSoftFrontEndGlobalVariables.ConfigSoftData.DirectoryData.AppPath, "Mold\\lib");

        /*if (LstMaterials.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, LstMaterials.SelectedIndex, ref ErrorFlag);
        }
        else
        {
            ModSoftOutput.UpdateMaterialScreen(this, 0, ref ErrorFlag);
        }*/
    }

    private void LstMaterials_SelectedIndexChanged(System.Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.MaterialType MaterialData = default(Mold_Power_Suite.Model.FrontEndStructures.MaterialType);
        short RINumber= Convert.ToInt16(LstMaterials.SelectedIndex);
        MaterialData = ModSoftInputMod.GetMaterialData(ref RINumber,ref SavePath,ref ErrorFlag);
       // var _with3 = this;
        this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Text = MaterialData.WetRefractiveIndex.ToString();
        this.TxtMDPrefix.Text = MaterialData.MDPrefix;
    }

    private void FrmAddMaterial_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (UpdateMaterialFile != null) {
            UpdateMaterialFile();
        }
    }


    }
}
```

I have made sure to add these lines in my `Program.cs` file in C# code

```
static  class Program
    {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
          Application.EnableVisualStyles();
          Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
          Mold_Power_Suite.View.frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
         // WindowsFormsApplication3.view.Form1 abc = new view.Form1();
          Application.Run(mainForm);
      }
    }
```

Here is the `Designer.cs`

```
namespace Mold_Power_Suite.View
{
    partial class FrmAddMaterial
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
            this.TxtMDPrefix = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CmdReturn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CmdEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.CmdAdd = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.LstMaterials = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.Label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.Label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.toolTip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // TxtMDPrefix
            // 
            this.TxtMDPrefix.AcceptsReturn = true;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Enabled = false;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.TxtMDPrefix.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 80);
            this.TxtMDPrefix.MaxLength = 0;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Name = "TxtMDPrefix";
            this.TxtMDPrefix.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.TxtMDPrefix.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 20);
            this.TxtMDPrefix.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // CmdRemoveMaterial
            // 
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 219);
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Name = "CmdRemoveMaterial";
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 25);
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.TabIndex = 5;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Text = "&Remove Material";
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CmdRemoveMaterial.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CmdRemoveMaterial_Click);
            // 
            // CmdReturn
            // 
            this.CmdReturn.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.CmdReturn.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.CmdReturn.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.CmdReturn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.CmdReturn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.CmdReturn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(89, 291);
            this.CmdReturn.Name = "CmdReturn";
            this.CmdReturn.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.CmdReturn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 25);
            this.CmdReturn.TabIndex = 15;
            this.CmdReturn.Text = "&Close";
            this.CmdReturn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // CmdEdit
            // 
            this.CmdEdit.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.CmdEdit.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.CmdEdit.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.CmdEdit.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.CmdEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 187);
            this.CmdEdit.Name = "CmdEdit";
            this.CmdEdit.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.CmdEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 25);
            this.CmdEdit.TabIndex = 4;
            this.CmdEdit.Text = "&Edit Material";
            this.CmdEdit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CmdEdit.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CmdEdit_Click);
            // 
            // CmdAdd
            // 
            this.CmdAdd.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.CmdAdd.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.CmdAdd.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.CmdAdd.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.CmdAdd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 155);
            this.CmdAdd.Name = "CmdAdd";
            this.CmdAdd.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.CmdAdd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 25);
            this.CmdAdd.TabIndex = 3;
            this.CmdAdd.Text = "&Add Material";
            this.CmdAdd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.CmdAdd.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.CmdAdd_Click);
            // 
            // TxtWetRefractiveIndex
            // 
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.AcceptsReturn = true;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Enabled = false;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 32);
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.MaxLength = 0;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Name = "TxtWetRefractiveIndex";
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 20);
            this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // LstMaterials
            // 
            this.LstMaterials.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
            this.LstMaterials.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.LstMaterials.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.LstMaterials.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
            this.LstMaterials.ItemHeight = 14;
            this.LstMaterials.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
            this.LstMaterials.Name = "LstMaterials";
            this.LstMaterials.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.LstMaterials.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 228);
            this.LstMaterials.TabIndex = 0;
            this.LstMaterials.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LstMaterials_SelectedIndexChanged);
            // 
            // Label2
            // 
            this.Label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.Label2.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.Label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.Label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 64);
            this.Label2.Name = "Label2";
            this.Label2.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.Label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 17);
            this.Label2.TabIndex = 8;
            this.Label2.Text = "Data File Prefix";
            // 
            // Label1
            // 
            this.Label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.Label1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.Label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
            this.Label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(152, 16);
            this.Label1.Name = "Label1";
            this.Label1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.No;
            this.Label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 17);
            this.Label1.TabIndex = 7;
            this.Label1.Text = "Wet Refractive Index";
            // 
            // FrmAddMaterial
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(10F, 19F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.CancelButton = this.CmdReturn;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(272, 255);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TxtMDPrefix);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CmdRemoveMaterial);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CmdReturn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CmdEdit);
            this.Controls.Add(this.CmdAdd);
            this.Controls.Add(this.TxtWetRefractiveIndex);
            this.Controls.Add(this.LstMaterials);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.Label1);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            this.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 14);
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5, 4, 5, 4);
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "FrmAddMaterial";
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultBounds;
            this.Text = " Add/Edit Material";
            this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.FrmAddMaterial_Enter);
            this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.FrmAddMaterial_FormClosed);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FrmAddMaterial_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        public System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TxtMDPrefix;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button CmdRemoveMaterial;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button CmdReturn;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button CmdEdit;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Button CmdAdd;
        public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TxtWetRefractiveIndex;
        public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox LstMaterials;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label Label2;
        public System.Windows.Forms.Label Label1;
        public System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip2;

    }
}
```

1. How to I make the application and all the corresponding popups look exactly the way they look in VB ?
2. The nee Windows ,when not active tend to go behind the application. I want them not to go outside the `Parent Window.`

How can I fix these?

Comment: It is pretty wrong in both, the VB.NET flavor is more wrong.  You gave it a toolwindow border style and claim it is a dialog.  But you don't use ShowDialog().  That produces Z-order problems, you *must* use the Show(owner) overload so it always stays on top of the owner window.  The VB.NET gets it more wrong, by the looks of it, by making these windows an MDI child window.  A toolwindow frame is not appropriate for such windows.

Comment: @HansPassant love your comments sir. Anything that you would like me to change ? but dont understand why the same code in VB has borders but not the C# one

Comment: @Apoorv the visual style you're getting in your application is itself an ugly, neglected part of Windows (semi-skinned MDI windows). I strongly advise you ditch WinForms and use WPF - the good news is that it still runs on .NET so you don't need to change any of your non-UI code.

Comment: You've commented out the event wireups in InitializeComponent - have you reproduced these elsewhere?

Comment: Yes I HV added in the. Events t

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
MatRef.Show();
```

write

```
MatRef.ShowDialog();
```

If that not working than add one more line before that

```
MatRef.TopLevel = false;
```

Sample Code:

ParentForm.Designer.cs

```
namespace MyPro
{
partial class ParentForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(231, 193);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 44);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "Show Dialog";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // ParentForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1059, 719);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "ParentForm";
        this.Text = "Parent Form";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
}
```

ParentForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyPro
{
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form f = new DialogWindow();
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
}
```

DialogWindow.Designer.cs

```
namespace MyPro
{
partial class DialogWindow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // DialogWindow
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(282, 255);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
        this.Name = "DialogWindow";
        this.Text = "DialogWindow";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: What I could achieve by using ShowDialog() that the window is not going in the background. but still the Border is not coming

Comment: Try this set FormBorderStyle Property as FixedSingle and set MaximixeBox and MinimizeBox as false of your dialog form.

Comment: Tried..its not happenning again

Comment: Can you post your for designer  code in your question?

Comment: Updated . Kindly check

Comment: dont understand what is the issue as I too have the same code in my window